# Remove unused JavaScript to reduce bytes consumed by network activity

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have issue with "https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/731015690569070?v=2.9.42&r=stable"
"https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-110217943-1&l=dataLayer&cx=c" [image]
what should I do? How can I Reduce unused JavaScript if I even cant find it.
I have to removed unused Javascript connect.facebook.net. is it possible?
[get in web site](https://easy-moving.ca/)

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot mentions both Facebook as Google Tag Manager.
Both assets to do not come with Joomla core.
So there must be some kind of 3th party extension that adds this.

Google Tag Manager
https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-110217943-1&l=dataLayer&cx=c

This all contains an id=UA-110217943-1 which looks a lot like a Google Universal Analytics implementation. To reduce unused Javascript and thus remove this call implies to remove the connection to Google Analytics.
Is that what you want?

The same goes for connect.facebook.net... It is a connection between your site and Facebook. If there is no need, then find out which 3th party extension is adding the Facebook pixel. Just after the start of `<body>` and before `<div class="wrapper">`.
`<img height=1 width=1 style=display:none src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=731015690569070&ev=PageView&noscript=1" alt="">`

Comment: Sir, Should I download the script in My data base and rumoved unused  code? In the future use it from base? can I  or it's not posible ?

Comment: I tryed to do it: `$document = JFactory::getDocument();
unset(
$this->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'https://connect.facebook.net/signals/config/731015690569070?v=2.9.42&r=stable'],
$this->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'https://www.google.com/js/th/78f0cHg-mss9TBwkXBH5e0namqWixOmUHR8LetvkC9Q.js']);`   dosent work

Comment: You should consider to remove the facebook integration if not needed. Otherwise accept the consequence of loading this external script. On the other hand... you can expect Facebook to do everything to provide you with a very optimised code. Continue to solve the other issues on your website as mentioned in the results of Google Pagespeed Insights

Comment: Sir, I have issue with scripts.  This is main issue what I have. there is four scripts what I would like solve

Answer (score 0):

To find out which plugins or other parts of your website load the JavaScript, you could **install that website on your local computer** and **use an IDE** (like PHPStorm, Netbeans, Visual Studio, etc) to analyse it.

You can run a Joomla website locally using an "AMP" stack (like LAMP, MAMP, WAMP, etc). With Akeeba Backup you can create a backup that you restore locally.

If you create an SQL dump from your Joomla database, and put that text file in your local Joomla folder, the IDE will also search in that.

Comment: Can you help Me Sir? Can you explain correct I got it. I should to install apache on My pc. Im able to using web site only use kind of server. My web site uses .php

Comment: There's some info about "Setting up your workstation for Joomla development" at the Joomla documentation website: https://docs.joomla.org/Setting_up_your_workstation_for_Joomla_development

Comment: I found out what plagin I need. Next step I have to insert My code. I did it. But something went wrong

Answer (score 0):

I could solved the problem.
but I dont know how to correct do it

```
<p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IDSJ0iMLq_U" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
```

I have that. It works so bad, okey.
how ot looks like:
[image]

What I made:

```
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="page1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="video1.css">
    </head>
<body class="page">
<div class="video">
    <a class="video__link" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDSJ0iMLq_U">
        <picture>
            <source srcset="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi_webp/IDSJ0iMLq_U/maxresdefault.webp" type = "image/webp"> 
            <img class ="video__media" src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/IDSJ0iMLq_U/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="7 step in moving a piano">
        </picture>
    </a>
    <button class="video__button" aria-label="play video">
        <svg width="68" height="48" viewBox="0 0 68 48"><path class="video__button-shape" d="M66.52,7.74c-0.78-2.93-2.49-5.41-5.42-6.19C55.79,.13,34,0,34,0S12.21,.13,6.9,1.55 C3.97,2.33,2.27,4.81,1.48,7.74C0.06,13.05,0,24,0,24s0.06,10.95,1.48,16.26c0.78,2.93,2.49,5.41,5.42,6.19 C12.21,47.87,34,48,34,48s21.79-0.13,27.1-1.55c2.93-0.78,4.64-3.26,5.42-6.19C67.94,34.95,68,24,68,24S67.94,13.05,66.52,7.74z"></path><path class="video__button-icon" d="M 45,24 27,14 27,34"></path></svg>
    </button>    
</div> 
<script src="video1.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

what I got:
[image]

what should I do?
It works better in My local pc

Comment: [get into the page](https://easy-moving.ca/piano-movers-toronto)

Comment: If you still have a problem, you must not communicate it as an answer.  It would be better if you edited your question to include any remaining issues to be solved.  Alternatively, if you don't want this page to be "a moving target", then you could ask a new question with your new/remaining requirements.

Comment: thank you Sir. I find it better rahter than keep this question s